# Overriding a CPT template file through functions.php

Tags: custom-post-types

Ok, so I am trying to override a CPT template file. Problem is, the theme I am working with is set up in a weird way (or at least in a way I can't quite figure out) and wants to pull a template file of single-cpt.php no matter WHAT I do. Even if I assign a template part to the post, the single-cpt overrides my selected template.

So, fine, I set out to override this template in my functions.php. After a lot of hunting and trial and error, I figure this out:

```
function is_post_type($type){
global $wp_query;
if($type == get_post_type($wp_query->post->ID)) return true;
return false;
}

function template_override() {
  if (is_single() && is_post_type('portfolio')){
  return locate_template('template-portfolio.php');
  }
  if (is_single() && is_post_type('product')){
  return locate_template('woocommerce.php');
  }
}

add_filter('template_include', 'template_override');
```

This DOES work... except it had the unfortunate side effect of now wanting to override ALL of my pages with this custom template. Thats why I added that call to a theme woocommerce template file, becuase I thought at first it was just messing with posts... but NOPE, it turns out this is messing with EVERY page. So, obviously, I screwed up something there in my code... I just can't figure out what. I've tried about a million other variations to try to call this template file, and this is the only one that has worked so far. Unfortunately, it seems to be overriding everying.

So, what am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `template_override()` function isn't returning anything if your conditions aren't met, which will break everything that doesn't meet your conditions. You need to pass the existing template through:

```
function wpse_283378_template_override( $template ) {
    // My conditions.

    return $template;
}
add_filter('template_include', 'wpse_283378_template_override');
```

Also, `is_post_type()` and `template_override()` are very generic names for functions, which increases the risk of conflict with other plugins and themes, prefix them with something unique to your project.

Defining an `is_post_type()` function is overkill anyway. Just replace `is_single()` with `is_singular( 'portfolio' )`:

```
function wpse_283378_template_override( $template ) {
    if ( is_singular( 'portfolio' ) ) {
        $new_template = locate_template( 'template-portfolio.php' );

        if ( $new_template != '' ) {
            return $new_template;
        }
    }

    return $template;
}
add_filter('template_include', 'wpse_283378_template_override');
```

Note that I also checked that the template file exists before returning it, this way if it doesn't it will fall back to the default instead of giving you a white screen.